# Is it possible to generate xml from SQL where I don't know the number of levels?

Tags: sql-server

I have this data structure :

```
Site    SiteDescription SiteParent
1       Test 1          -1
2       Test 2          1
3       Test 3          1
4       Test 4          2
5       Test 5          2
6       Test 6          4
7       Test 7          4
8       Test 8          7
```

Using a SQL Query and FOR XML, I want to generate an xml result with the following format:

```
<sites>
  <site id="1" desc="Test 1">
    <site id="2" desc="Test 2">
      <site id="4" desc="Test 2">
        <site id="6" desc="Test 2" />
        <site id="7" desc="Test 2">
          <site id="8" desc="Test 2" />
        </site>
      </site>
      <site id="5" desc="Test 2" />
    </site>
    <site id="3" desc="Test 3" />
  </site>
</sites>
```

I need a format like that and I realise I can do it but including sub-queries and using FOR XML and PATH, etc.

My problem is that I don't know how many levels down this will go.  It could be 3 or 10.

I'm not a fan of hard-coding a specific number of sub-queries to hopefully cover all future child levels.

Is there a recursive way to produce this structure where it doesn't matter how many levels there are today, tomorrow, or next year?

Comment: is this using c# api?  regardless, you pretty just need to implement 2 methods: addChildNode(parent, child) and findNode(id)(node), then sort by parent node id and call findNode, addChildNode in a loop. ezpz

Comment: Try using CTE. CTE works really good for fetching hierarchical data.

Comment: @believesInSanta, It's not using C#, just straight SQL in a MSSQL database, I want to call a sproc to generate the XML and dump it into a field for retrieval later.

Comment: @TheShooter, I'll have a look at CTE.. thanks